# Wordpress update totally broke the install. Main page now displays empty rss feed

Tags: rss, updates, automatic-updates

Hey guys-
A friend of mine just did an auto-update for the most recent wordpress upgrade.
Upon completion, her site began to display her rss feed on the front page instead of well, her front page.
the rss feed also appeared to be empty.
Upon further inspection, it appears that EVERY page goes to that empty feed page (including the admin panel link).
Lastly, it seems that the main url wants to add an additional // at the end of the URL when hitting the root of the domain.

Have any of you heard of anything like this?
Said friend went to me looking for help because I'm usually a wellspring of knowledge on such things, but this is one problem Ive never come across.

For reference, this is the site:
http://lizconley.com/

Thanks for any input you might have!

Comment: Any chance you had made a backup prior updating?

Comment: I don't know if she did, as this wasn't my install, but a friend's. I'm posting this because I've never even heard of someone having a problem like this- and I'm genuinely curious about what could have possibly gone wrong for it to fail so catastrophically. I'll ask her if she backed up.

Comment: Check [Chris_O's answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13342/wordpress-update-totally-broke-the-install-main-page-now-displays-empty-rss-feed/13359#13359), I think he nailed it. You won't need a backup then.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the kommiku plugin.  Disable the plugin by renaming the kommiku folder in the wp-content/plugins directory.

A lot of other users seem to be experiencing [bugs and problems](http://wordpress.org/tags/kommiku) with the plugin.

Also check your .htaccess file and see if any there are any weird redirects.  If there are you can delete it and WordPress will generate a new one when you flush your rewrite rules by saving your permalink settings.

Make sure you are not using default permalinks according to the kommiku plugin documentations.

Here is a screenshot of the 302 Redirect in the headers.

If you view the source of the page there is a broken xml feed then the page content underneath.

[image]

> Upon further inspection, it appears
>   that EVERY page goes to that empty
>   feed page (including the admin panel
>   link).

The blog posts and category archives are fine but to access the admin you will have to rename the wp-content/plugins/kommiku folder and possibly clean out the .htaccess file in the root directory.

http://lizconley.com/page/2/

http://lizconley.com/category/prints/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reverting to the default Theme (TwentyTen), and also flushing the mod_rewrite rules, by saving the Permalinks settings again?

Answer (score 0):

The files and database are probably still there. Google's cache shows the site at 3.1 already, so I wonder what update was being done?

So get into the server via FTP and rename your plugins folder to force deactivate all plugins. If that doesn't work, delete the .htaccess file (and regenerate permalinks afterward.) If that doesn't work, manually upload new copies of all Wordpress core files and folders, except for wp-config.php and /wp-content/.